# Do you ask puzzles only on Puzzling or ask methods of how to solve one?

Tags: discussion

It is so interesting to witness various people figuring out correct answers to the most complex of puzzles asked. I don't know how to cultivate such technique of solving puzzle. But I want to know the techniques and cultivate puzzle solving skills. Is it acceptable on main site to ask such questions?

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it is absolutely acceptable to ask such questions.

Originally, PSE's main focus was supposed to be questions *about* puzzles. How do I solve this kind of puzzle? How do I create this kind of puzzle and make it just challenging enough? Who was the first person to make this kind of puzzle? What sort of puzzle might be appropriate for a group of 4-6 very bright 9-year-olds? Etc.

When PSE started having a lot of *actual puzzles* as questions, there was a good deal of soul-searching about whether that was appropriate -- exactly the *opposite* of your question here!

So, indeed, you are very welcome to ask questions about puzzle-solving techniques. (But ... Introspection is hard, and you shouldn't be too disappointed if the answers are less helpful than you're hoping for. In some cases the best answer someone can give to "how do you solve these things?" might be "well, I'm really clever and I know a lot" :-).)

Comment: Thanks. Sure I will keep that in mind :)

Comment: Although there doesn't appear to be a tag on "asking a question about a puzzle" or "not a puzzle", I've taken to prefacing my questions with "This is a genuine question about a puzzle, not a puzzle" just to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @Tas I believe the tag "puzzle-creation" is the tag used for questions *about* puzzles

Comment: My understanding is that that's about when one is creating their own puzzle, not when they're asking about an already made puzzle. I might be wrong though

Comment: "A question about the creation and development of puzzles. Not to be used for requesting the creation of a puzzle." is the description of that tag.